# How to receive multiple responses for a SOAP request in C#?

Tags: c#, api, soap, tcp

I am creating a SOAP web request to call TCP/IP port for response. When I call on Short Route it works fine but when I call on Long route it receives initial "Processing" response and then stops. This request actually receives multiple "Processing" messages before finally sending actual results. I don't know how to receive multiple responses and finally when I get actual response then close the socket/API call. When I check in WireShark (see screenshot below) I see receiving multiple responses for the call but can only receive first response and not able to capture all the responses in C# Windows form. Any help greatly appreciated.

Code below

```
            HttpWebRequest request = Create_Message(MESSAGE_TYPE_POST, iInterface);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(iRequestMessage);
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            using (var response2 = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                Stream responseStream = response2.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                if (response2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                        oResponseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        requestStream.Close();

                        Console.WriteLine(oResponseText);
                }
            }
```

[image: Wireshark image showing multiple responses]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved it. I was not able to find what port SOAP web service was receiving response. But I was able to configure web service to communicate on a certain port and then capture data pockets received on that pocket and save it into a file for further processing.

```
            HttpWebRequest request = Create_Message(MESSAGE_TYPE_POST, iInterface);
            request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = new BindIPEndPoint(DefineIpPort);
```

Delegate code below

```
    private IPEndPoint DefineIpPort(ServicePoint servicePoint, IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, int retryCount)
    {
        return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 55061);
    }
```

And then receive data like in code below

```
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
            // enter IP address and Port on which web service is running
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xx.xx.xx.xx"), 55061));
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.HeaderIncluded, 1);
            byte[] inBytes = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
            byte[] outBytes = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, inBytes, outBytes);
            byte[] bytesReceived = new byte[50048];
            
            List<string> results2 = new List<string>();
            int counter2 = 0;
            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
            string folder = @"C:\datafiles\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "-data.txt";               
            
            while (true)
            {
                int nBytesRead = socket.Receive(bytesReceived); 
                string responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, nBytesRead);
                Add_Text_To_Output(responseData);
                results2.Add(responseData);
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                counter2 += 1;
                if (counter2 > 100)
                    break;
            }
            File.WriteAllLines(folder, results2);
```

This code is not perfect yet but it is definitely capturing all data pockets I need. If you need to debug how web service is running and getting data, install WireShark filter on remote server IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `while` statement to periodically read from the response stream until you know that the received response text is the last one (I guess that you know what how determine the last response). Then break `while` statement and close request stream.

```
using (var response2 = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
{
    if (response2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream responseStream = response2.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
        while (true)
        {
            oResponseText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(oResponseText);
            if (oResponseText == "Completed")
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        requestStream.Close();
   }
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but only first response works subsequent ones fail to read. SOAP request only gets 1 response it appears. I need a solution to find the port number which SOAP request ran and keep that Port open to get additional responses.

Comment: @manjuvreddy Is the server where you send request public? So, I can try to call the server and checks response?

Comment: Hi @user2250152 sorry this is not public server.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this solution and worked great for me, thank you !!!!
Only problem I have is it is getting too much data from the socket because of reading every 20 milliseconds. I had to use IndexOf function to search and filter data I was looking for and then within each response it had multiple lines of data and again had to go through and remove unnecessary lines of data.
Also adding following lines of code to HttpWebRequest helped to get better answers from server.

```
        oRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
        oRequest.ContentLength = 0;
        if (iMessage != string.Empty)
            myWebHeaderCollection.Add(iMessage);  // IntefaceName
        oRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        oRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
```

You are hardcoding the port number. Use code below to get free available port.

```
    public int FreeTcpPort()
    {
        TcpListener l = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ClientIP.Text), 0);
        l.Start();
        int port = ((IPEndPoint)l.LocalEndpoint).Port;
        l.Stop();
        return port;
    }
```